# About Noether currents for conformal symmetries

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, lie-algebra

I´m reading "[Conformal algebra on Fock space and conjugate pairs of operators](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.82.104012)" of
Klaus Sibold and Eden Burkhard, there the authors write all Noether currents in terms of the energy momentum tensor $T_{\mu \nu }$. I know that one can actually do this for spacetime translations:
\begin{equation}
\delta \phi=-\varepsilon^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi \implies J^{\mu}=-\varepsilon^{\rho}T_{\rho}^{\mu} 
   \text{ (current for spacetime translations)}
\end{equation}
been $T_{\rho}^{\mu}$ the canonic energy momentum tensor.

I have two questions:

> why the current for the dilatiation symmetry, given by
> [image] could be putting in a simmilar form [image] ?

And a last question. I calculate the Noether current for the dilatations as usuall, that is calculating the border term $K^{\mu}$ (wich coincides with $\varepsilon x^{\mu} \mathcal{L}$ for the real scalar field) and then computing $D^{\mu}=$[image]
I obtained an expresion for the dilaton current wich I don't realice if it is the same or not why the athors one:
My current,
$$D_{\mu}=\varepsilon [(\partial^{\mu}\phi)(1+x^{\lambda}\partial_{\lambda})\phi-\frac{1}{2} x^{\mu}(\partial^{\lambda}\phi)(\partial_{\lambda}\phi)],$$

author's current,

[image]

I could check that both of them carry to the same charge, wich is

[image]

> Can we go from my current to the author's current? are they the same? If not, why the charge is the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what improvement terms are?

Comment: yes. Actually they work with the improve energy momentum stress-energy tensor? why is it of any help?